# Retain JavaFX stage position when hiding

Tags: java, javafx

**Is there a simple way to retain the position of a JavaFX `Stage` that has been hidden?** In Swing, when a `Frame` was hidden and made visible again, it would retain the position and dimensions it had when it was hidden. Is there a simple way this behavior can be achieved in JavaFX?

In my application, I have a main window with toggle buttons which are meant to be tied to showing / hiding secondary windows. Unfortunately, every time a user hides one of those secondary windows (using the toggle buttons), they open up at the center of the screen again if the user tries to make them visible again.

Any simple way around this?

```java
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Platform.startup(() -> {});
    Platform.runLater(() -> testStagePos());
}

protected static void testStagePos() {
    final BorderPane p = new BorderPane();
    p.setCenter(new Label("Random label"));
    p.setPadding(new Insets(100));  // Just so window isn't too small

    final Stage popup = new Stage();
    popup.setScene(new Scene(p));

    final BorderPane cp = new BorderPane();
    final ToggleButton b = new ToggleButton("Show popup");
    b.setOnAction(e -> {
        if (b.isSelected())
            popup.show();
        else
            popup.hide();
    });
    cp.setPadding(new Insets(50));
    cp.setCenter(b);

    final Stage control = new Stage();
    control.setScene(new Scene(cp));
    control.show();
}
```

Comment: Before you hide the `Stage` save the `Stage's` position. After you show it again reset the `Stage's` position.

Comment: I may not be relevant to the question but where is `Platform.startup(()` defined ? I can't find it in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html).

Comment: Surprising.. I expect the Stage to keep the current position. As an alternative you can use iconification. `setIconified` saves the current position.

Comment: @KDM Thanks for the iconification suggestion! Unfortunately my application can open up to 15 different popups and the iconified windows still show up in the task bar. Understandably, it's an annoyance for users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this just after creating the popup.

```
    popup.setOnShown((e) -> {
        popup.setX(popup.getX());
        popup.setY(popup.getY());
    });
```

Building up on https://stackoverflow.com/a/48822302/600379

Comment: Note that this is alternative to `popup.setX(50);popup.setY(50);` . No need for both. +1

Comment: Thanks!! This did the trick! I'm a little confused about why it works though. I expected that the position information would have been lost at the closing. But the fact that this works seems to suggest that it isn't really lost just reset AFTER being shown...

Comment: @anishthecoder had a look at the Stage code. `Stage` is keeping two variables `implicitX` and `implicitY` and once set - it uses those. If not set it calculates each time on `show`.

Answer (score 3):

If you set any initial position to popup, it will retain its **last** position when hidden.
**All** you have to change is add this after defining `popup`: 
 
`popup.setX(50);popup.setY(50);`

Test it by:

```
private static void testStagePos() {
    final BorderPane p = new BorderPane();
    p.setCenter(new Label("Random label"));
    p.setPadding(new Insets(100));  // Just so window isn't too small

    final Stage popup = new Stage();
    popup.setScene(new Scene(p));
    popup.setX(50);popup.setY(50); //set initial position

    final BorderPane cp = new BorderPane();
    final ToggleButton b = new ToggleButton("Show popup");
    b.setOnAction(e -> {
        if (b.isSelected()) {
            popup.show();
            b.setText("Hide popup");
        } else {
            System.out.println(popup == null );
            popup.hide();
            b.setText("Show popup");
        }
    });
    cp.setPadding(new Insets(50));
    cp.setCenter(b);

    final Stage control = new Stage();
    control.setScene(new Scene(cp));
    control.show();
}
```